# Find initial value, given the Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the initial value ,

\begin{equation} 
F(s)=\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+10}
\end{equation}

this is the question, I can implement the  inverse laplace method but I do not know what to do at the last stage means after inversion. Now which method should I follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

[Initial value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_theorem):

$$ \lim_{t \to 0} f(t) =\lim_{s \to  \infty} s F(s)$$

[Final value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem):

$$ lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = \lim_{s \to  0} sF(s)$$

**Update**

In your case, the initial condition, or $f(0)$ can be calculated from IVT (Initial Value Theorem):

$$ f(0)= \lim_{t \to 0^+} f(t) =\lim_{s \to  \infty} s F(s)=\lim_{s \to  \infty} \frac{s(s+1)}{(s+1)^2+10}=\lim_{s \to  \infty} \frac{s^2}{s^2}=1$$

And the final result is:

$$f(0)=1$$

If you are curious about what is $f(t)$, here it is:

$$f(t)=\cos(\sqrt{10}  t)\times e^{-t}$$

Comment: dont understand ...can u please describe more .?

Comment: @FazlayRabbi You look for f(0). Am I right?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi, I approved the edit, however I did not recognize any difference.

Comment: Better to use not "$lim$", but "$\lim$" to better representation. I've just edited that.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi I see, thanks

Comment: i know the theorem bt dont know how to apply it in this paticular math ...should i put s=infinite to get initial condition

Comment: @FazlayRabbi, see my update.